# Python + OpenCV: Mask image with RGB pixels from another image

Tags: python, arrays, image, opencv, matrix

I have an RGB video and a single keyframe from that video. In that keyframe, the user will apply a binary mask. 
I want to create a mask of the video where pixels have values that exist in the keyframe's masked region.

In other words, I want to create a list of RGB pixel values that exist in the mask of the keyframe, and create a mask of all other frames on the condition that the pixel values exist within the list. Pixel values can be (0,0,0)-(255,255,255)

My current implementation, although technically correct, is extremely inefficient, and I imagine there must be something better.

```
    count = 0
    for x in sequence
        img = cv2.imread(x)
        curr = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],dtype = np.uint16)
        for x in range(img.shape[0]):
            for y in range(img.shape[1]):
               tuple = (img[x][y][0],img[x][y][1],img[x][y][2])
                if tuple not in dict:
                    dict[tuple] = count
                    curr[x][y] = count
                    count+=1
                else:
                    curr[x][y] = dict[tuple]
        newsequence.append(curr)


    #in another function, generate mask2, the mask of the keyframe
    immask = cv2.bitwise_and(newsequence[keyframe],newsequence[keyframe],mask=mask2[index].astype('uint8'))
    immask = [x for x in immask.flatten() if x != 0]

    #for thresholding purposes (if at least 80% of pixels with that value are selected in the keyframe)
    valcount= np.bincount(immask)
    truecount = np.bincount(newsequence[keyframe].flatten())
    frameset = set(immask)
    framemask = list(frameset)
    framemask = [x for x in framemask if (float(valcount[x])/float(truecount[x]))>0.8]

    for frame in range(0,numframes):
        for val in framemask:        
            mask[frame] = np.where((newsequence[frame]==val),255,0).astype('uint8')
```